# Data Model in excel 2010 and 2013 // data retrieval

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2010

In Excel  [2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff838417.aspx) and [2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194775%28v=office.14%29.aspx) there is the notion of WorkbookConnection, which represents a connection to an external source of data. We can access them through PowerPivot or other tools.

One particular type of connection is the OLEDB connection (but there are other kinds), which after refresh gets the data according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff838765%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

I would like to **access those data** the workbook has locally, coming from those connection.

=> Is there a way to have access to a direct property (a range/ListObject (aka table)) ?

For the moment, it seems the only option is to retro-engineer the convention used for the different kind of sources and lookup heuristically tables based on names.. (It seems trivial, but I can't find the answer in the documentation )

Comment: update : there is a way. the documentation is just awfully badly scattered around.... I'll update the question when I go back to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got you right?

but my solution to this problem is making the same connection in the PowerPivot, then you can see all the data the workbook has locally, edit it etc. and pretty much use it the same way.